# WPG browser text size or zoom

Tags: browser, text, controls, size, zooming

Is it possible to adjust the "size" of the browsers controls rendered output, ie text size or zoom out?

Im wanting a small browser visible on a form just as a preview to what a html page will render like.
so Id like it to be as small as possible

any ideas on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not outside of [badly supported proprietary land](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531189%28VS.85%29.aspx).